# Field specific errors on repeated field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, error-handling

I am required to display errors under specific fields depending on the situation. In my case there can be two. Which are `Password is empty` and `Passwords do not match`. Currently all the messages gets displayed under the `password.second` field.

I need to display `Password is empty` error under the `password.first` field and `Passwords don not match` under the `password.second` field.

I tried to generate the errors separately via `{% for error in form.password.first.vars.errors %}` and  `{% for error in form.password.second.vars.errors %}` but failed as the two error messages I require only gets rendered when I use `{% for error in form.password.vars.errors %}`. I have been at this for quite a while and returned empty handed. The implementation is as follows,

I am using a `repeated` field to implement the `password` and `confirm password` as follows,

```
$builder->add( 'password', 'repeated', array( 'type' => 'password','required' => true,  'invalid_message' => ErrorMessages::PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH, 'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field form-control')),'first_options'  => array('label' => false,'error_bubbling' => true,'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-4 control-label')),'second_options' => array('label' => false,'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-4 control-label'))));
```

And the `password entity` validation is as follows,

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {    

  /**
   * @Assert\Email(message=ErrorMessages::EMAIL_ADDRESS_INVALID)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message=ErrorMessages::EMAIL_ADDRESS_EMPTY)
   */
  private $email;

  /**     
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message=ErrorMessages::PASSWORD_EMPTY, groups={"full"})
   */
  private $password;
  ....
```

I render these two fields in the `twig` in the following manner,

```
<div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
  {{ form_label(form.password.first, "Password") }}
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    {{ form_row(form.password.first) }}                      
  </div>              
</div>
<div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
  {{ form_label(form.password.second, "Confirm password") }}
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    {{ form_row(form.password.second) }}
    <span class="help-block">
      {% for error in form.password.vars.errors %}
        {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')~'' }}
      {% endfor %}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle, or is this all original work?  Just wondering where the current behaviour comes from.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the bit where you added the `repeated` field yourself!

Comment: @frumious thanks for the reply.. yea i am using repeated field :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the convenient `repeated` field, then you're probably stuck - the way `repeated` works is to duplicate, using a ValueToDuplicatesTransformer, the field you add into two fields containing the same data, and it ensures that they are the same at the point where the Transformer turns submitted form values back into model data (not using normal constraints).  From validation's PoV, there is only one field, so you can't choose which textbox the error goes against.

But there may be other options if you want to sort it out yourself!

You could make a [Custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).  To achieve the behaviour you're after I think you'll need it to be a [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator), so that it has access to both fields at once, and can compare them.  However, that will again mean that the error gets applied at a higher level than you want, so probably won't work.

So probably the way is to manually test the fields in your Controller, and add the relevant error directly to the field with which you want it to be associated, something like the following.  You need to split the password field into two so that you can test them against each other, so put the `NotBlank` constraint on the first field.

*Controller*

```
// ...

$password1 = $form->get('password1');
$password2 = $form->get('password2');
if ($password1->getData() != $password2->getData() )
{
    $password2->addError(new FormError("Passwords do not match!") );
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this descriptive answer. I will try this out and post back :)